# Anchor within same page with some height?

Tags: html, tags

I am creating a resume web page which link parts below it using 'a' HTML tag.

It looks link this :-
[image: Pic before clicking on link]

When i click on a link ("What I Do").It scrolls down to the division specified.But the navigation bar hides the heading of the division(Text in Red Box) .How can i scroll only till the begining of the division so that the heading is below the navigation bar.

Upon Clicking "What I Do" link on navigation bar :- 
[image: Pic after clicking on link]

Note :
The navigation bar is a sticky one,so it always is on top of the page.

Code of navigation bar :

```
<div id="navbar">
<p id="name_in_navigation">Abhimanyu</p>
<a href="#footer">Contact</a>
<a href="#works">My Works</a>
<a href="#tech_skills">Technical Skills</a>
<a href="#what_i_do">What I Do</a>
<a href="#edu_qualification">Educational Qualifications</a>
<a class="active" href="#my_pic">About Me</a>
```

Comment: @kiner_shah sry that Q is totally different...

Comment: Is you *navbar* always sticky, or it becomes sticky and stays when you scroll down?

Comment: @abdul-wahab It becomes sticky when i scroll below it....and i want it that way

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly your header is fixed and when you scroll the div is going behind the header, try to add some padding-top to the `div` and check if solve the problem.

If you inspect the `div` once the page has scrolled you will see that the beginning of the `div` it's the top of the window (behind the header), with padding-top you can add the height of the header and solve the problem

Comment: But wouldn't adding padding top create unnecessary empty space?

Comment: yes but I think it's the only solution. Basically, the Header will hover all the div you are going to tag, less the page has finished and it can force the page to scroll at the top of the window. It's the problem of using fixed header.